# Git checkout not fetching the branch from repo to local folder in Mac machine

Tags: git

I am working on Develop branch in Mac machine and wanted to change to remote branch "qa". So I performed "git checkout qa" branch and checked the branch using "git branch" it shows qa branch. But when I checked the files it shows the Develop branch files and qa branch files are not present in the path. Why git branch shows "qa" if no files are changed in the local folder.

Comment: Did you git pull?

Comment: Sorry, can't look at that repo page, I get `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`.

Comment: Can you paste the output into your q. from `git log --oneline --graph --decorate -n 10 develop qa`?

Comment: @matt: I found .git file is getting downloaded every time when I am cloning the repository. Is there a way to ignore .git file during cloning.

Comment: Makes no sense, `.git` folder _is_ what you are cloning. It is the repository. Without it, this would not be a clone.